# Django/Python: Best Practice/Advice on handling external IDs for Multiple Multi-directional External APIs

Tags: python, django, integration, api-design

So this is more of a conceptual question, and I am really looking for someone to just help point me in the right direction.  I am building a middleware platform where I will be pull data in from inbound channels, manipulating it, and then pushing it out the other door to outbound channels.  I will need to store the external id for each of these records, but the kicker is, records will be pulled from multiple sources, and then pushed to multiple sources.  A single record in my system will need to be tied to any number of external ids.

a quick model to work with:

```
class record(models.Model):
    #id 
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")
    category_id = model.ForeignKey(category)

class category(models.Model):
    #id 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")

class channel(models.Model):
    #id
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="")
    inbound = models.BooleanField()
    outbound = models.BooleanField()
```

Obviously, I cannot add a new field to every model every time I add a new integration, that would be soooo 90s.  The obvious would be to create another model to simply store the channel and record id with the unique id, and maybe this is the answer.

```
class external_ref(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharfieldField()
    internal_id = models.IntegerField()
    external_id = models.IntegerField()
    channel_id = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('model', 'internal_id',)
```

While my example holds simply 4 models, I will be integrating records from 10-20 different models, so something I could implement an a global level would be optimal.  Other things I have considered:

- Overwriting the base model class to create a new "parent" class that also holds an alpha-numberic representation of every record in the db as unique.
- Creating an abstract model to do the same.
- Possibly storing a json reference with channel : external_id that I could ping on every record to see if it has an external reference.

I'm really an open book on this, and the internet has become increasingly overwhelming to sift through.  Any best practices or advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact issue and yes there is not much information on the web in using Django this way. Heres what Im doing - haven't used it long enough to determine if its "the best" way.

I have a class IngestedModel which tracks the source of the incoming objects as well as their external ids. This is also where you would put a unique_together constraint (on external_id and source)

```
class RawObject(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    A Table to keep track of all objects ingested into the database and where they came from
    """
    data = models.JSONField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class IngestedModel(models.Model):

    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source,on_delete=models.CASCADE)# 1 or 0
    raw_objects = models.ManyToManyField(RawObject,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

then every model that is created from ingested data inherits from this IngestedModel. That way you know its source and you can use each external object for more than 1 internal object and vise versa.

```
class Customer(IngesteModel):
class Order(IngestedModel): 
...
etc.
```

Now this means there is no "IngestedModel" table but that every model has a field for source, external_id and a reference to a raw object (many to many). This feels more compositional rather than inherited - no child tables which seems better to me. I would also love to hear feedback on the "right" way to do this.